# gsutil cp -Rn s3://foo gs://bar is slow and consuming a lot more ingress than egress

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to replicate data in S3. We're talking about a few hundreds of thousands of reasonably big blobs (many in the 1GB-100GB range). The operations are performed from a machine in US East, for S3 blobs in US Standard.

gsutil 3.34 seems to take a lot more ingress than egress, even after running for a few hours.
I tried to tweak a few options but didn't get anywhere.

Example measure: 78387.82 KB/s in vs 3154.36 KB/s out. I'd be fine getting a 2x ratio, but 10x+ really doesn't feel right.

Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 2):

Well, turns out the warm-up time was a lot longer than I expected. Not sure which operations take so much ingress for so long; I would suspect something like a lot of blob listings (maybe one per process, or something like that)?

I started the sync around 12:00 on the graph below.

[image: Graph from AWS]

I just tried to restart `gsutil -m cp -Rn s3://foo gs://bar` and I observe the same I/O pattern (starting with tons more ingress than egress, I'll keep an eye for gradual improvements in the first 10-20 hours).

`iostat` doesn't show any write activity that can't be explained by logging (very few KB/s), so it's not buffering on disk.

Comment: Do you have a lot of small files? I'd expect small files to result in a large amount of bucket listing ingress traffic, with a small amount of egress going out in comparison

Comment: Well, yes and no. Some statistics about file sizes, using `s3cmd ls -r s3://foo | awk '{print $3;}' | statistik` (from the `baze` gem): https://gist.github.com/pcarrier/75b2a24115fe1729973f

Comment: I definitely wouldn't expect hours and hours of slowness from that, given how `s3cmd ls -r` runs in less than 20 seconds...

Comment: @PierreCarrier same problem here. I don't know if that comes form `boto`, `gsutil`, or the way they interact, but this surely is very far from optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Something's quite odd about 10x more being downloaded than uploaded. I mean, the data's gotta be going somewhere, right?

Some potential suggestions:

- Could it be a bandwidth issue? gsutil cp copies files down from S3 to the local machine, and then up to GCS from there. If your ISP limits your upload speed, it could be the cause. Perhaps GCS is downloading the data just fine, but is being throttled uploading it again.
- Have you tried the "-m" flag? gsutil defaults to copying one file at a time. With -m, you can upload many files in parallel, potentially greatly increasing the speed.

Comment: The files are probably getting gzipped on upload.

Comment: Aha! That could very well be it.

Comment: Except the files are gzipped (by GNU gzip without any flags) in the first place...

Comment: I would probably catch a bandwidth issue by monitoring the disk space. However it seems very stable with less than 3GB used total (across filesystems). Memory usage also remains stable, around 2GB used and 500MB cached (out of 64GB :D).

Comment: I did try `-m`, which does help quite a lot but maintains the same bandwidth ratio. The provided measure actually uses `-m`.